# Digital signing of web document

Tags: java, ios, spring, security, model-view-controller

I want our staff who have iPhones to be able to get members of the public to digitally sign a document which starts out as a Spring based web-form.

This form is only present on our intranet and only completed by our staff.

My research so far has considered a number of possible solutions:

1. Electronic wet ink signature on the screen of the phone;
2. Using the fingerprint scanner on phone to capture a specific finger of the member of the public and store it digitally;
3. PKI system;

The purpose is to prove a particular person signed a document.

1 technically possible, but doesn't count for much as it could easily be copied.

Is it possible to capture a fingerprint via the browser and javascript on a iOS device?

Can 3 be made to fit this sort of scenario?

Comment: Option 2 is not possible. Only the Secure Enclave chip on the device has access to raw fingerprint data.  I am not sure how option 3 would work; you would need each member of the public to have their own key pair and you would need some way of getting them to use it. Option 1 is probably the only practical solution

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to guarantee non-repudiation of the form by the member that signed it, I would recommend to use 3.

The process could go like this:

1. A key pair `(K+, K-)` (public, private) is generated for the user
2. The document is signed against `K-(information_input_by_user)`
3. You store K+ together with your user's records in some database.
4. Fetch K+ from the database and use it to prove the user is the authentic author of the signature

Note: *information_input_by_user* in line 2 could be any personal information related to the user (his own input) used to authenticate him.

Comment: Does the K- information remain private, else there is nothing to stop anyone with admin access to the DB signing there own records?

Comment: I would say that we don't need K- anymore since the member of public signs the form only one time. The purpose is to retrieve the personal information input of the signer from the signature with K+. The intranet is assumed to be accessed by staff only so I suppose the records are safe